# How to get ivms-4200 soft to reconnect to remote DVRs after Internet connection is reestablished?

Tags: camera, dvr, cctv, ivms

I've set up a computer to receive the video flows from several remote Hikvision DVRs. To do that I installed the IVMS-4200 software and I configured it to connect to the remote DVRs through the Hikconnect platform. It works really well, except when the Internet connection is lost for more than 5 minutes approximately. When the Internet connection is reestablished, the software doesn't try to reconnect to the remote DVRs. I need the computer to works as autonomous as possible because my client knows almost nothing about computing.

So, do you know how I can achieve that automatic behaviour? Is there any configuration to achieve that?

I've tried the different softwares which are offered by Hikvision, like the different versions of the ivms-4200 or the soft Hilookvision, but in all cases I found the same problem.

I hope that you can help me. :-)